# For a given Azure subnet how to find the first two available private IPs?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have subnet that shows 3 available IPs as below. Is there a quick way to fetch the first 2 available IPs?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For a given Azure subnet how to find the first two available private IPs?

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

In my environment, I have 58 available IP addresses.

[image]

You can use the azure cli command below to fetch the first 2 available Ip addresses.

**Command:**

```
az network vnet subnet list-available-ips --resource-group <your-resource-grp> --vnet-name vnet01 -n subnet-1 --query [0:2]
```

**Output:**

```
[
  "10.1.6.5",
  "10.1.6.6"
]
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[az network vnet subnet | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/vnet/subnet?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-vnet-subnet-list-available-ips-examples)

Comment: Is there a PowerShell version as well?

Comment: It is an Azure CLI command you can download from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont wish to mix and match `Az CLI` with `Az Powershell` command. So Anything feasible with `Az Powershell`?